# Array of int colors into Bitmap on Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, bitmap

I have an *int*[] array of colors outputted from a Bitmap. Let's call it *bigArray*. 
I want to crop it, so I want all the colors in between, say, *bigArray*[20] and *bigArray*[100]. So I use a for loop to output those integers into a new array, *smallArray*[].

Now here's the trick. Even though I have the color values I want, whenever I try to draw them on a new Bitmap of the appropriate size via *setPixels*(), I get weird noise on the output instead of my image.

The code in a nutshell:

```
// Static variables width-height-bmp and so on are declared prior to this

public void imageToArray(){
    //reading my Bitmap into an array
    imageArray = new int[width*height];
    bmp.getPixels(imageArray,0,width,0,0,width,height);

    //creating a new array and an output Bitmap
    int[] checkArray = new int[checkLength];
    bmpCheck = Bitmap.createBitmap(checkWidth, checkHeight, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

    //outputting the needed values
    for(int i=0,col=20;col<100;i++)
    {
        checkArray[i]=imageArray[col];
    }

    //setting the color values to the pixels of the new Bitmap
    bmpCheck.setPixels(checkArray,0,width,0,0,width,height);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Maybe, there is a better way to do that?
Would be thankful for any help.

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you want to achieve - do you want to crop the image?

Comment: In fact, I am pulling color values only for certain positions in the image, and then compose them in a new Bitmap. Interesting enough, this works if I use getPixel() method.

Comment: still have no idea what you try to do ..